# Icons with different outline weight - is it possible to adjust?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionicons

I'm using 3 Ionicons side by side:

```
<ion-icon name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="attach"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
```

As the picture below shows, the first icon looks lighter than the other ones.

[image]

Is it something that I can adjust?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `-webkit-text-stroke: desired pixels`

you can change the stroke of the icons.

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
<ion-icon style="-webkit-text-stroke: 1px;" name="add"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: it works for text but not for the icon... anyway thanks for the answer!